# TermDocumentMatrix doing unrequested cleaning (e.g. removing punctuation)

Tags: r, tm

The `TermDocumentMatrix` function of the `tm` package is not functioning according to my understanding of the documentation. It seems to be doing processing on the terms that I have not requested.

Here is an example:

```
require(tm)
sentence <- "Astrology: I am a Capricorn Sun Cap moon and cap rising...what does that say about me?"
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(sentence))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus, control = list(wordLengths = c(1, Inf), 
                                                 removePunctuation = FALSE))
rownames(tdm)
```

We can see from the output that the punctuation has been removed, and the expression "rising...what" has been split:

```
 [1] "a"         "about"     "am"        "and"       "astrology" "cap"       "capricorn" "does"      "i"         "me"        "moon"      "rising"    "say"       "sun"       "that"     
[16] "what"
```

In the [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33954853/r-how-do-i-keep-punctuation-with-termdocumentmatrix), the issue was with the tokenizer which was removing the punctuation. However, I am using the default `words` tokenizer, which I don't believe does this:

```
> sapply(corpus, words)
      [,1]           
 [1,] "Astrology:"   
 [2,] "I"            
 [3,] "am"           
 [4,] "a"            
 [5,] "Capricorn"    
 [6,] "Sun"          
 [7,] "Cap"          
 [8,] "moon"         
 [9,] "and"          
[10,] "cap"          
[11,] "rising...what"
[12,] "does"         
[13,] "that"         
[14,] "say"          
[15,] "about"        
[16,] "me?"
```

Is the observed behaviour incorrect, or what is my misunderstanding?

Comment: try VCorpus (Volatile Corpus), for some reason this does keep the punctuation and remove from TermDocumentMatrix removePunctuation = FALSE and will work as you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got a `SimpleCorpus` object, which [came with tm package version 0.7](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/news.html) and which - according to `?SimpleCorpus` -

> takes internally various shortcuts to boost performance and minimize
>   memory pressure

```
class(corpus)
# [1] "SimpleCorpus" "Corpus"
```

Now, as `help(TermDocumentMatrix)` states:

> Available local options are documented in termFreq and are internally
>   delegated to a termFreq call. This is **different for a SimpleCorpus**. In
>   this case all options are processed in a fixed order in one pass to
>   improve performance. **It always uses the Boost Tokenizer** (via Rcpp)...

So you are *not* using `words` as tokenizer, which would indeed give you

```
words(sentence)
 [1] "Astrology:"    "I"             "am"            "a"             "Capricorn"     "Sun"           "Cap"          
 [8] "moon"          "and"           "cap"           "rising...what" "does"          "that"          "say"          
[15] "about"         "me?"
```

As stated in the comments, you could make your corpus explicitly a Volatile `?VCorpus` to gain back full flexibility:

> A volatile corpus is fully kept in memory and thus all changes only
>   affect the corresponding R object

```
corpus <- VCorpus(VectorSource(sentence)) 
Terms(TermDocumentMatrix(corpus, control = list(tokenize="words"))
```

Comment: Now `VCorpus` gives me the desired behaviour, as you explained. However, with a "real" corpus it is huge: 1.4Gb versus 36Mb for a `SimpleCorpus` and also about 50% slower to work with.